# Sometimes my request comes in as HTML and other times as TEXT/*. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload

I have an AJAX upload action for my Rails app.  Sometimes it comes in as:

```
Started POST "/products/temp_upload" for 63.148.78.244 at Fri Sep 24 21:34:27 +0000 2010
  Processing by ProductsController#temp_upload as HTML
```

And everything runs smoothly.

Other times it comes in as:

```
Started POST "/products/temp_upload" for 63.148.78.244 at Fri Sep 24 21:49:35 +0000 2010
  Processing by ProductsController#temp_upload as TEXT/*
```

And I get a 406.

The only consistency I see is that it works on Windows and fails on OS X.  Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the browser making the request will accept all text response formats